# Cat Facts API discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to find out how to generate cat facts using API. So far, I have this code:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def catfact(self, ctx):
      async with aiohttp.ClientSession().get("https://catfact.ninja/fact") as response:
          fact = (await response.json())["fact"]
          length = (await response.json())["length"]
          embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Random Cat Fact Number: **{length}**', description=f'Cat Fact: {fact}', colour=0x400080)
          embed.set_footer(text="")
          await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

It is supposed to send a cat fact in an embed. So far, it works but I'm still getting an error:

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f6338088d60>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7f6338bcb640>, 76247.003680814)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7f6338088d00>
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: "it works but I'm getting an error". I feel like only one of those can be true

Comment: It sends the embed with the fact, but I'm still getting that error.

Answer (score 2):

This error you're encountering seems to be caused by the fact that you don't close the session after you open it, as referenced by this [aiohttp GitHub issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/2643).

The quickest fix would probably be to simply close the session after you send the cat facts to the user. But your `with` statement doesn't give back a session to work with, it just gives a response. So, you could instead split that into two `with` statements, like so:

**Before:**

```py
async with aiohttp.ClientSession().get("https://catfact.ninja/fact") as response:
    ...
```

**After:**

```py
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact") as response:
        ...
```

However, now that these `with` statements are split, the session is closed automatically after the code within its `with` statement is finished; before, it didn't close, because your `with` statement didn't expose the session itself, just the response. By exposing the session *itself* (before these changes, you were not doing that) in a `with` statement, Python will automatically close it when it has finished running the code within.

Full code:

```py
@commands.command()
async def catfact(self, ctx):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact") as response:
      fact = (await response.json())["fact"]
      length = (await response.json())["length"]
      embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Random Cat Fact Number: **{length}**', description=f'Cat Fact: {fact}', colour=0x400080)
      embed.set_footer(text="")
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      # await session.close() # <--- here, but is not necessary
```

*If you do still run into the error elsewhere though, you can add* `await session.close()` *(last line in code above) to close the session manually, but it shouldn't be necessary.*

Comment: By the way, you can see how it works in the test discord server I created, if you'd like: https://discord.gg/9enrNzBX

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to a GET request to gather the data. I did this using `requests`.

- `requests.get()` sends a GET request to the specified url.
- `.json()`  builtin JSON decoder.

```py
import requests

@commands.command()
async def catfact(self,ctx):
    data = requests.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact').json()
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f'Random Cat Fact Number: **{data["length"]}**', description=f'Cat Fact: {data["fact"]}', colour=0x400080)
    embed.set_footer(text="")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Remember to install `requests` using

```
python -m pip install requests
```

[image: A sample test]

Comment: [Aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) would be better for a discord bot as requests is blocking.

Comment: @Cloud What do you mean by blocking ?

Comment: I mean that it will block the thread that the async event loop runs in. There is more info on it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html) under the Blocking Code section.